# \n not displaying as line break in vscode editor

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, line-breaks, ubuntu-20.04

I'm saving some text in `json` format using `python`. I'd like to see the `\n` as line-break but `vscode` is not displaying it as line-break but rather as \n. Can anyone help me out?

Here's the text of saved json file

```
{
  "text":"I need to read properly.\nBut can't do so as \n not displaying as line-break"
}
```

Version of vscode is 1.52 and ubuntu is 20.04

P.S: `vscode` is also not displaying \n as line-breaks in simple text file

Comment: In json files, the escape sequences are shown just like that. But if you load this json in python again, the escape sequences should perform their specified task.

Comment: I was also suspecting this. But what about text file? When I copied this text in plain text file line break didn't show.

Comment: That's because escape sequences are components of programming languages only and not json or txt files